# Getting issue on python only with Ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, python, telegram

I know that I should ask this on Stackoverflow, but I did it and no one there could help me. So I decided ot try there, because problem happens only on Ubuntu. There is my code:

```
async def main() -> None:
    await dp.start_polling(bot)


def create_new_bot(token, char_id, char_name, bots, greeting):
    async def start_bot(dp, bot):
        event_loop.create_task(dp.start_polling(bot))

    def bot_init(event_loop, token, char_name, char_id, greeting):
        bot = Bot(token=token)
        dp = Dispatcher()

        event_loop.run_until_complete(start_bot(dp, bot))

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        event_loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        if bots is not None:
            for bot in bots:
                try:
                    bot_init(event_loop, bot[2], bot[4], bot[3], bot[5])
                except:
                    pass
        else:
            bot_init(event_loop, token, char_name, char_id, greeting)

        event_loop.run_forever()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM bots")
    bots = cur.fetchall()
    th = Thread(target=create_new_bot, args=(None, None, None, bots, None))
    th.start()
    asyncio.run(main())
```

This is full error that I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/python_projects/ai_character_311/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py", line 507, in start_polling
    loop.add_signal_handler(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/asyncio/unix_events.py", line 107, in add_signal_handler
    raise RuntimeError(str(exc))
RuntimeError: set_wakeup_fd only works in main thread of the main interpreter
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-8' coro=<Dispatcher.start_polling() done, defined at /root/python_projects/ai_character_311/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py:457> exception=RuntimeError('set_wakeup_fd only works in main thread of the main interpreter')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/asyncio/unix_events.py", line 105, in add_signal_handler
    signal.set_wakeup_fd(self._csock.fileno())
ValueError: set_wakeup_fd only works in main thread of the main interpreter

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/python_projects/ai_character_311/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py", line 507, in start_polling
    loop.add_signal_handler(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/asyncio/unix_events.py", line 107, in add_signal_handler
    raise RuntimeError(str(exc))
RuntimeError: set_wakeup_fd only works in main thread of the main interpreter
```

I get this error only on Ubuntu, with Windows it works fine

Comment: I'm not very good with Python, but this looks like either an incompatibility or implementation issue. Try confirming it's done right and works by default, preferably with similar code that doesn't do anything extra.

Comment: The stacked `def` and `if __name__` like kind of strange and leave a taste the the program has an improvable structure.
On the key question: are you sure you can run an async event loop in a thread? To me the error message hints towards that this is the problem.

Comment: As the question was already asked at Stack Overlfow: please edit your post and add a link to the discussion there, maybe it is helpful.